# Various divs with same classname and onclick function to call to open corresponding message div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with my javascript function that is working for now. I want to change it to a Jquery function but I don't know how.

I have a page with a lot of div's with the same class ("message"). These message windows opens when clicked on "delete" with a onclick function delete_on('. $id .') Inside the message window is a onclick function to close the window.

Message window that opens and closes:

```
<div class="message">
    Sure you want to delete?
    YES <a onclick="delete_off('. $id .')">NO</a>
</div>
```

Link that opens the message window:

```
<a onclick="delete_on('. $id .')">delete</a>
```

Javscript functions:

```
function delete_on($id) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("message")[$id].style.display = "block";
  document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
}

function delete_off($id) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("message")[$id].style.display = "none";
  document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
}
```

I give every onclick function an $id that is counting up for every div and "delete" link. The javascript function knows which div it has to open caused by the $id.

The [$id] part in the function is the problem. I can't make it work in Jquery?!
Can someone help me? Is there another way to combine the javascript function to the right div?

Comment: What jQuery have you tried so far?

Comment: function delete_on(id) {
 $('.message')[id].css("display", "block");
 $('body').css("overflowY", "hidden"); }

Comment: What happens if someone clicks on `YES`?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting event listeners using `$.on` like so:

```
$('.message').on('click', function () {
  // $(this) is the thing clicked...
});
```

Once you get the `$(this)` you can navigate around that element relatively. To get its parent, for example:

```
$('.message').on('click', function () {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
});
```

And manipulate it however you wish.

https://jsfiddle.net/ozdzug33/1/

Good luck!

Comment: why `event.target` and not `$(this)`

Comment: Oh yes! I don't really use jQuery anymore so forgot about it. Will update!

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I mean. My problem is that I dont know how to use id in function delete_on(id) to open the corresponding div. It is working with normal javascript but how do I use it in jQuery?

Comment: I get it worked with giving every div an id like delete2, delete3 etc. with the counting number in it. I can use it in jQuery with: $('#delete' + (id))